# NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset isn't working

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I've two `ObservableCollection` named `BuyOrders` and `SellOrders`. If I remove items from one of these in this way:

```
var list = order.OrderType == OrderType.Buy ? BuyOrders : SellOrders;
var o = list.Where(x => x.OrderNo == order.OrderNo).First();
list.Remove(o);
```

`ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged` event works. If I, however, update an item like this:

```
var list = order.OrderType == OrderType.Buy ? BuyOrders : SellOrders;
var o = list.Where(x => x.OrderNo == order.OrderNo).First();
o.Price = order.Price;
o.Quantity = order.Quantity;
```

`CollectionChanged` event doesn't work! Isn't it a valid `Reset`?

Is there anything wrong in my code?

---

**EDIT**

This is the handler for `BuyOrders`:

```
void BuyChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    AllOrder order = null;
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            try { order = e.NewItems[0] as AllOrder; }
            catch (Exception) { return; }
            if (order.ItemCode == ItemCode) Buys = GetOrders(ClientCode.BuyOrders).OrderByDescending(x => x.Price);
            break;

        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
            Buys = GetOrders(ClientCode.BuyOrders).OrderByDescending(x => x.Price);
            break;
    }
}
```

I've similar handler for `SellOrders`

The `ObservableCollection` I'm using is named `AsyncObsetion` and has been implemented in this way:

```
public class AsyncObsetion<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private SynchronizationContext context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    public AsyncObsetion() { }
    public AsyncObsetion(IEnumerable<T> list) : base(list) { }

    void RaiseCollectionChanged(object param) => base.OnCollectionChanged((NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)param);
    void RaisePropertyChanged(object param) => base.OnPropertyChanged((PropertyChangedEventArgs)param);

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current == context) RaiseCollectionChanged(e);
        else context.Send(RaiseCollectionChanged, e);
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current == context) RaisePropertyChanged(e);
        else context.Send(RaisePropertyChanged, e);
    }      
}
```

to get rid of `App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Comment: [NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedaction) is called when collection is changed *drastically*. Second snippet doesn't change anything apart from properties of item. This is not monitored by `ObservableCollection<T>`, you will have to manually subscribe to each item `NotifyPropertyChanged` event. That's what binding does.

Comment: @Sinatr, how to do that manually? Could you please post that as an answer?

Comment: What's the problem with invoke? Another thread? You shouldn't set property of item from another thread, it may be bound by the view.

Comment: @Sinatr, the app i'm testing is using `SocketAsyncEventArgs`, which probably is multithreaded by deafult, so I'd have to write a lot of `App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` to update lists if I didnt use that `AsyncObsetion`!

Comment: @Sinatr, to solve the issue, right now I'm using a variable for the index of `o` before updating and after update I'm replacing that index, in this way I get notification for `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace`, not the best way I think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is subscribe to the PropertyChanged of each of the orders in Orders, and trigger a CollectionChanged event

```
foreach(var order in orders) {

  order.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) {
       // if you need to to only respond to a certain property
       // if (args.PropertyName != nameof(Order.Property)) return; 
       // do any other code here
       Orders.RaiseCollectionChanged(sender);
    };

}
```

Comment: hasen't it been done in the implementation of `AsyncObsetion<T>`?

Comment: @EmonHaque: Cleary not. What makes you think it has?

Comment: You need to think about ICollectionChanged as responding to changes to the collection as a whole, and not to changes within the items of the collection. If I have a bag of marbles, and I add a marble, remove a marble, or empty the bag of marbles, each of those will trigger a collection change event. But if I reach in and squeeze one of the marbles, I haven't actually changed the bag, so no event.

So when you initialize the bag, you need to subscribe to the changes on each of the marbles, so that when I reach in and squeeze one, it will notify me that it's be changed.

Comment: @mm8, `protected override void OnPropertyChanged`, for collection changed it's `OnCollectionChanged`!

Comment: @lavantgarde, replacing is better in case where collection changes frequently, right?

Comment: @mm8, oh! It actually has subscribed to collectionchanged not propertychanged, so lavantgarde is right.